# Arabic characters using preg_match() function

Tags: function, character, preg-match, match, arabic

I am trying to use preg_match() to check Arabic and English characters only,

i used this code:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zأ-ي]*$/",$name)
```

but still, it is not working.

EDIT: The code that does not work:

```
if($name == '' || $email =='') {
    echo("<div class=\"error\">fill all fields</div>");
}
else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zأ-ي\s]*$/",$name)) {
     echo("<div class=\"error\">Only letters and white space allowed</div>");
}
else if (strlen($name) < 6) {
    echo("<div class=\"error\">NONONONO les than 6</div>");
}
else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo("<div class=\"error\">WORNG EMAIL</div>"); 
} else {}
```

Comment: Use `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zأ-ي]*$/u",$name)`

Comment: Yes dear, I used this code as well. However, i faced a problem when i wanted to check the string length to be not less than 6 characters using strlen function, it does't work well after applying the preg_match() function.

Comment: Use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

Comment: What is the full relevant code that you have problem with?

Comment: ` if($name == '' || $email =='')
 {
   echo("<div class=\"error\">fill all fields</div>");  
 }
 else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zأ-ي\s]*$/u",$name)) 
 {
  echo("<div class=\"error\">Only letters and white space allowed</div>"); 
 }
 else if (mb_strlen($name) < 6)
 {
  echo("<div class=\"error\">NONONONO les than 6</div>"); 
 }
 else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
   echo("<div class=\"error\">WORNG EMAIL</div>");
 }
 else
 {}`

Comment: It Works perfectly; Thank you a lot..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `/u` modifier with `preg_match` to make sure the pattern and string are treated as Unicode strings and the `strlen` must be replaced with [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) to correctly count Unicode characters:

```
else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zأ-ي\s]*$/u",$name)) {
     echo("<div class=\"error\">Only letters and white space allowed</div>");
}
else if (mb_strlen($name) < 6) {
    echo("<div class=\"error\">NONONONO les than 6</div>");
}
```